# PHP login error

Tags: php

Hello i have a big problem .. I'm creating a user login site but the problem is that if i have 2 or more users in database and if i try to log in with my 2nd user's credentials it only gives me the 1st users info . Any help would be appreciate it.

Login.php

```
include '../init/init.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    // ...
    $username = $_POST['log_username'];
    $password = $_POST['log_password'];

    $login = login($username, $password);
    if ($login === false){
        die(msg1(0, 'Password is incorrect.'));
    }else{
        $_SESSION['id'] = $login;
        die(msg1(1,"members.php"));
        exit();
    }
}
```

users.php (I have all my user functions here)

```
    <?php

// ...
function user_id_from_username($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query_user_id = mysql_query("SELECT (`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
    return mysql_result($query_user_id, 0, 'id');
}

function login($username, $password) {
    $id = user_id_from_username($username);

    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    $query_login = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'");
    return (mysql_result($query_login, 0) == 1) ? $id : false;

}
?>
```

And this shows the profile after login:

```
// ...
if (logged_in() === true){ 
  $session_user_id = $_SESSION['id']; 
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users"); 
  $id = 'id'; 
  $username = 'username'; 
  $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql); 
}
$errors = array();

// show profile based on $rows
```

Comment: > `it only gives me the 1st user in database info.`
Do you mean that the visitors `$_SESSION['id']` is always 1 after `login.php`? Or that `members.php` always shows info of the first user?
You might try to use `LIMIT 1` in the end of the queries where you only want and expect one result.

Comment: members.php always shows infor of 1st user .. and still not working with limit1

Comment: The 2 username you are having is unique or what?

Comment: yes of course they are unique becuase in register.php i setup num_row_check so i dont let a user submit a username if there is a same username in DB

Comment: Isn't `echo '<div id="mini_profile">This is '.$rows['username'].'\'s profile.</div>';` in the wrong block (move it into the if almun)? And whats `$rows['username']`. `$rows` is not declared in `members.php`, afaic. You mean `$username` or `$firstname`?

Comment: Run your query manually . what your are getting?

Comment: when i echo out the session id i get the 2nd users id but the 1st users information

Comment: `$rows['username']` here where you are assigning result into `$rows`

Comment: im getting the $rows from init.php CODE ----> <?php

session_start();
error_reporting(1);

require 'connect.php';
require 'users.php';
require 'general.php';

if (logged_in() === true){
 $session_user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
 
 $id = 'id';
 $username = 'username';
 
 $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
}

$errors = array();

Comment: Why are you outputting info about the logged in user when `id=Username` in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the code in the comments section I would advice changing the code to:

```
$session_user_id = $_SESSION['id']; 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE `id`='$session_user_id'");
```

I'm going to assume that you sanitized `$_SESSION['id']` beforehand.

Comment: You got the answers bro ... thanks a lot